# Присвоить класс объекту при выборе значения select

Tags: javascript, css

Имеется объект:

```
@foreach( $data as $row )
    <div class='row' style='clear:both;width:1200px;'>
        @foreach( $row as $day=>$gymArray )
            <div class='cell'
                 style='width:170px;float:left;;text-align: center;max-height:370px;overflow: auto'>
                @foreach( $gymArray as $gym=>$gymInfo )
                    <div id="timetable-cell-gym"  style='clear:both'>
                        <p  id="time-text">{{ $gymInfo[ 'time' ] or '' }}</p><hr id="hr-time" style="width:20%"/>
                        <h5 style="margin-bottom: -6px; margin-top:-10px"><strong id="group-name">{{ $gymInfo[ 'group' ] or '' }}</strong></h5><br>
                        {{ $gymInfo[ 'trainer' ] or '' }}<br><hr id="after-worker-line" style="width:70%; margin-bottom: 15px"/>
                        <p style="margin-top: 9px"> {{ $gymInfo[ 'status' ] or '' }}</p>
                        <small id="gym-name">{{ $gym or '' }}</small>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

При его редактировании в форме выводится селект статуса:

```
{!! Form::model($columns, ['class' => 'form', 'method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['api.columns.update']]) !!}
<input name="id" value="{!! $columns->id !!}" type="hidden">
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('time', 'время', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('time',  null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    <p class="help-block">в формате: "8:25"</p>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('service_title', 'группа', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::select('service_title', $groups,  null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('worker_name', 'Тренер', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::select('worker_name', $trainers,  null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('timetable-select', 'статус', ['class' => 'timetable-select']) !!}
    {!! Form::select('timetable-select', $status, old('status'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="buttons" align="right">
    {!! Form::submit('Обновить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ url('api/columns') }}" style="background: #832032; color: #fffbd8;">Назад</a>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Необходимо, чтобы при сохранении изменений в этой форме присваивался статус объекту. На данный момент пробовал такой вариант JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       if ($("#timetable-select").change){
            className = $(this).val();
            oldClassName =  $("#timetable-cell-gym").attr("oldClass");
                            $("#timetable-cell-gym").attr("oldClass",className);
                            $("#timetable-cell-gym").removeClass(oldClassName).addClass(className);
        }
    });
```

При обновлении класс объекта не изменился. Как можно изменить скрипт для его работоспособности?

Comment: Вы уверены, что это javascript?

Comment: @Visman а есть другие варианты?

Comment: Какие другие варианты, если я спросил "причем тут javascript?". Код вами представленный в вопросе не тянет на javascript, вот и все.

Comment: @Visman исправил пост, надеюсь так понятнее

Comment: Вы в скрипте `js` пишите `#timetable-select` (id), а как я понял по разметке у Вас `class="timetable-select"`, стало быть надо `.timetable-select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Обновлено.**
Спасибо @VenZell. Я не заметил, что `.timetable-select` является классом `label`, а не `select`, следовательно событие `change` на него вешать бесполезно.

Стоит манипулировать именно с тегом `select`.

Можно использовать `~`:

```
$('.timetable-select ~ select:first').on('change', function() {
    className = $(this).val();
    $("#timetable-cell-gym").attr("class", className)
});
```

Comment: По прежнему не изменяет класс

Comment: Александр, обратите внимание, что класс `.timetable-select` навешен на `label`. Именно поэтому, во-первых, не сработает событие `change` при выборе значения в выпадающем списке, а во-вторых метод `val()` ничего не вернет. Этот класс должен быть навешен на тег `select`. Добавьте это в ответ.

Comment: @bastadien обновил ответ

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich увы продолжает сопротивляться и не присваивает класс объекту

Comment: @bastadien взгляните на "живой" пример [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/xqgjy797/) Возможно увидите разницу  в чём-то.